# Editting python 2-dimensional array without for-loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

So, I have a given 2 dimensional matrix which is randomly generated:

```
a = np.random.randn(4,4)
```

which gives output:

```
array([[-0.11449491, -2.7777728 , -0.19784241,  1.8277976 ],
   [-0.68511473,  0.40855461,  0.06003551, -0.8779363 ],
   [-0.55650378, -0.16377137,  0.10348714, -0.53449633],
   [ 0.48248298, -1.12199767,  0.3541335 ,  0.48729845]])
```

I want to change all the negative values to 0 and all the positive values to 1.
How can I do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where()`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(4,4)
a = np.where(a<0, 0, 1)

print(a)

[[1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(a<0).astype(int)
```

This is one possibly solution - converting the array to boolean array according to your condition and then converting it from boolean to integer.

```
array([[ 0.63694991, -0.02785534,  0.07505496,  1.04719295],
   [-0.63054947, -0.26718763,  0.34228736,  0.16134474],
   [ 1.02107383, -0.49594998, -0.11044738,  0.64459594],
   [ 0.41280766,  0.668819  , -1.0636972 , -0.14684328]])
```

And the result -

```
(a<0).astype(int)
>>> array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```